# What is the equivalent value for apache configuration

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, nginx, apache-config

I need to convert following nginx rule to Apache configuration.
can anyone help me.

```
location /chat {
   rewrite            /chat(/.+)$ $1 break;
   proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000;
   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
   proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
   proxy_buffering    off;
   proxy_send_timeout 310;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look to be rewrite stuff you want but rather proxy stuff.

Comment: yes it is proxy stuff. so it means I need to modify httpd.conf? if so then what should be there in httpd.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html), I think the `ProxyPassMatch` directive is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert them to Apache2 like:

```
ReWriteEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/chat"  "http://localhost:8000" flushpackets=on 
ProxyPassReverse "/chat"  "http://localhost:8000"
ProxyTimeout 310
```

in your `<VirtualHost *:443>` or `<Location /chat>` section